# Obtener índice de un registro desde un evento delegado

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando obtener el índice de un registro de una tabla, para lo cual he delegado el evento conforme se muestra en el código. Al imprimir el mensaje en consola, no tengo problema; no obstante, al usar `return` la consola me muestra `undefined`.

Lo que quiero hacer es que la función `obtenerIndice()` devuelva el índice, para luego usar ese índice para modificar el registro en la función `modificarRegistro()`.

```
function obtenerIndice(elemento, etiqueta) {
    let indice;
    elemento.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target.nodeName === etiqueta) {
            indice = e.target.parentNode.rowIndex
            //console.log(indice); <-- imprime el índice en consola correctamente;
            return indice; // <-- solo muestra 'undefined'
        }
    });
}

const index = obtenerIndice(tabla, 'TD');
console.log(index); // <-- solo muestra 'undefined'

function modificarRegistro(index) {
    //código para modificar el registro basado en el índice obtenido en la función obtenerIndice();
}
```

Comment: te devuelve undefined porque al ajecutar la funcion esta se ejecuta linea por linea sin esperar que se haga click... termina la funcion y como no hay return queda como undefined! deves re-evaluar tu logica o colocar que estas intentando y cual es el resultado esperado...

Comment: Si, creo que estás bastante confundido. `obtenerIndice` solo define un evento al elemento cuando le hagan click, y no devuelve nada (por eso el console.log muestra undefined)... Otra cosa muy distinta es lo que se ejecuta en ese elemento cuando se le haga click a él. Si lo que quieres es que cuando den click se modifique el registro, deberías ejecutar la funcion modificarRegistro después de esta linea, así: `indice = e.target.parentNode.rowIndex; modificarRegistro(indice);`